# Matlab script edit - model recognition

Tags: matlab, simulink

I try to alter the properties of a `MatlabFunction` on `Simulink`. The recommended commands here are below.

```
open_system('my_model');    
S = sfroot    
B = S.find('Name','myBlockName','-isa','Stateflow.EMChart');
```

The '`BlockName`' is a `MatlabFunction` on the model `my_model`. The content of `B` is '`0×1 empty handle`' and `S.Name` gives `DefaultBlockDiagram`. It seems it does not recognize the opened model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command is "slroot"